# RabbitMQ embedded broker stuck when my network (wifi) is on

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

This really seems to be strange. I'm running a simple integration test using the embedded broker:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.arivera.oss/embedded-rabbitmq -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.arivera.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-rabbitmq</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I run this test on a Mac OS/X. As expected, the broker binaries gets downloaded first and then attempts to start. While starting it is too slow (seems to have been stuck) and times out. A strange observation here is if I run the same test with my network (wifi) off, then everything runs as expected.

Something on my network settings doesn't seem to play well with the embedded rmq.

My /etc/hosts file looks perfectly fine as the hostname resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Perhaps worth mentioning that I use Spring Boot 2.0 to run these integration tests.

Really unsure of what's happening here!

Comment: M-m-m. Is it confirmed that the problem is exactly in case of Spring Boot or just Spring AMQP? I mean don’t we have the same problem when we use this embedded RabbitMQ just with raw Java? The idea is too narrow the ring around an issue. Maybe it is worth to be in touch with Arivera as well?

Comment: Check in the logs and see if there is anything useful there.

Comment: Nothing specific in the logs I could see. To make it more mysterious, this works perfectly fine on a different wireless network (I tried from a different wifi and it all works just fine)!